# Why do we need to connect the computers to a LAN cable when we can use the internet

Tags: computer-networks

why don't we put a network card or usb adapter to connect to wifi and connect all the computer to the internet without LAN and WAN cables 
i may act stupid so please explain it to me my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a cable, you can get up to ten gigabit per second transfer rates. WiFi is much slower. In addition, in one area you can only use at most three WiFi channels at the same time, so in an office with 100 computers you have a problem.

You can also run Ethernet over 100 meters with good cables, try that with WiFi.